# Request private network access in windows using Rust

Tags: windows, rust, lan

I have a Rust app that requires LAN access to send requests to local devices, however Windows sometimes ask the users about how the app should use the network, but users press OK without put a check on allow private network access, so I need a way to trigger this dialog again for the user, how may I request "Private Network Access" again

I believe I should use "windows-rs" crate, however I have zero knowledge in Windows